# bash : adding a name value to a structure using bash

Tags: bash

I want to do the  following in bash for example say i have the following names rather than creating three seperate arrays to hold the contents of LC1 , LC2 and LC3 i thought it might be best to create a tree structure in bash or maybe someone might have a neater solution - I need to do this in bash .

```
 LC1
    Test1
    Test2
 LC2
    Test3
    Test4
 LC3
    Test5
    Test6
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simulate a multidimensional structure.
With *bash4*, for instance, you could use an associative array:

```
declare -A a=(
  [LC1]="Test1 Test2"
  [LC2]="Test3 Test4"
  [LC3]="Test5 Test6"
    ) 

for k in "${!a[@]}"; do
  printf '%s\n' "$k"
  set -- ${a["$k"]} # by default split on white space, tab and newline
                    # you can use another delimiter, if you wish
  for e; do
    printf '\t => %s\n' "$e"
  done
done
```

The code produces:

```
4.1.10(4)-release$ for k in "${!a[@]}"; do
>   printf '%s\n' "$k"
>   set -- ${a["$k"]} # by default split on white space, tab and newline
>                     # you can use another delimiter, if you wish
>   for e; do
>     printf '\t => %s\n' "$e"
>   done
> done 
LC1
         => Test1
         => Test2
LC3
         => Test5
         => Test6
LC2
         => Test3
         => Test4
```

Bare in mind that the set command will reset your positional parameters.

Comment: Note that LC1 LC2 and LC3 are the root which also has name  so i could have a root_array that has (LC1,LC2,LC3) then LC1 array has Test1, and Test2. How can i add a string to this multideminsional structure ?????

Comment: @killio : try experimenting with the code that @DimitreRadoulov has provided you. The answer to your question is inside it. (a hint is to print comment out most of the code inside the for loop. Good luck.

Comment: Firstly thx for the above. I am running bash 3.2.25  I have tried running the above and I get the following output  [0] =>Test5           =>Test6 Any ideas why the rest of the array isn't printed out.

Comment: @killio, *bash 3.x* doesn't have associative arrays. I prefer not to use pure shell for complex data structures.
If I really have to, with *bash* < 4 I would use a regular array, something like this:

`a=(
 'LC1 Test1 Test2'
 'LC2 Test3 Test4'
 'LC3 Test5 Test6'
 )`

`for k in "${a[@]}"; do
  printf 'key: %s\n' "${k%% *}"
  set -- ${k#* };
  printf 'values:\n'
  printf '\t=> %s\n' "$@"
done`

Comment: thanks again for that . But on question i want to do some manipulation on Test1, Test2 etc  I am using $k thinking it was first item in the array . how can i can i work with each of the elements in teh array ???

Answer (score 0):

@killio, I'm posting a new answer, because the comments provide limited formatting.

You could modify the array like this: just to give an example, 
if you want to double the last character of the elements:

```
#!/bin/bash


a=( 
  'LC1 Test1 Test2' 
  'LC2 Test3 Test4' 
  'LC3 Test5 Test6' 
  ) 

printf '\nthe array before:\n\n' 
printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}"


for ((i=0; i < ${#a[@]}; i++)); do 
  k=${a[i]%% *} es=${a[i]#* }
  set -- $es
  for e; do
   (( !c++ )) && es=$e${e#${e%?}} || es="$es $e${e#${e%?}}"
  done
  a[$i]="$k $es"; c=0
done


printf '\n\nthe array after:\n\n' 
printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}"



 $ ./s

the array before:

LC1 Test1 Test2
LC2 Test3 Test4
LC3 Test5 Test6


the array after:

LC1 Test11 Test22
LC2 Test33 Test44
LC3 Test55 Test66
```